# How can I configure a Flask app to use a Rails production DB for authentication, I'm not familiar with their underlying password salting and such

Tags: python, flask

I need to hook into a "legacy" Rails app which isn't maintained anymore.  Both the Python and Rails app will be going against the same database but that shouldn't be a problem.  Primarily I just need to know how to login / change passwords from the Python/Flask app.

Comment: What type of authentication and password storage was used on the Rails app and what type of authentication do you want to use on the Flask app?

Comment: I don't have access to the Rails system right now but I believe it's implemented with the basic/"standard" salting system which many people use when they're writing their first Rails apps which doesn't store plain text passwords.  I'm not very pick on the Flask side of things, if it's compatible with the Rails system then I'm happy.

Comment: Well the problem is that there are a few competing systems for authentication and they have settings to configure the type of encryption and salting. You would need to know this information before anyone can tell you how to access the data from Flask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bcrypt is what Rails uses.

You can use [flask-bcrypt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Bcrypt) to match it.

When you get your hands on the Rails app, see what version of Rails it uses and upgrade it.

As of Rails 3.1, you can use the SecurePassword module to easily generate passwords: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb